# Javascript regex for decimal validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function allowDecimal(txt) {
        var theEvent = txt.htmlEvent || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var regex = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|)*$/;

        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if (theEvent.preventDefault)
                theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }

<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeypress="allowDecimal(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is not allowing `.` to be entered so can some one help me what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

try this regex

```
  <script type="text/javascript">    
   function allowDecimal(txt) {
    var theEvent = txt.htmlEvent || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /^\d*\.?\d*$/;

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault)
            theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Allowing decimal but multiple decimal points should not allow

Answer (score 0):

you can also write like this without any regex for only one decimal validation:

```
var str = "hello.world"
var str2 = str.split(".");
var validate = str2.length;
if(validate != 1){
   alert("Decimal present");
}
else{
   alert("No decimal found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var decimal=/^[+-]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$/;
```

This matches an (optional) sign,

folllowed by any number of digits with an optional decimal point followed by digits,

or a decimal point followed by digits.